Has anyone done a thorough check of the [symbolism] tag's usage? Should we?
At the time of writing, this site's 11th largest tag (with over 200 questions) is symbolism. This is way larger than, say, allusions with 71 questions or allegory with 15 questions. Stay tuned to understand why I'm mentioning these other tags ...

I recall that, in the very early days of the site, the symbolism tag was being used quite liberally on any question about any sort of deeper/indirect meaning of something in a work of literature, regardless of whether it counted as "symbolism" in a strict literary sense or not. I think it was even our #1 biggest tag at some point during private or early-public beta.
Nowadays, my gut feeling is that we as a community have shifted towards a stricter, more technically correct, usage of the symbolism tag, only using it on questions that are actually about symbolism in the strict sense, while increasing the use of other tags like allegory for things that in previous times we might have tagged symbolism.
Usage of the tag has definitely declined over time: 11 / 631 = 1.7% in 2024, 7 / 738 = 0.95% in 2023, 7 / 727 = 0.96% in 2022, 16 / 1003 = 1.6% in 2021, 34 / 1130 = 3.0% in 2020, 12 / 648 = 1.9% in 2019, 27 / 849 = 3.2% in 2018, 97 / 1487 = 6.5% in 2017.

Hence my question: has anyone been through all the questions tagged symbolism to see if they really should all have this tag according to current site standards? If I'm right that we're now using this tag in a stricter way than before, then it doesn't make sense to have old 2017 questions still tagged symbolism that shouldn't be according to current practice.
I guess my question is really in three parts: (1) am I right that we're using this tag now in a stricter way than before? (2) has anyone checked/retagged old questions according to current standards? (3) if not, should we?
Relevant previous meta posts (all from 2017):

About the [allegory] and [symbolism] tags (in which I proposed making allegory a synonym of symbolism, a proposal which was - quite rightly, I now feel - shot down in flames)
What should the symbolism tag be used for? (in which the top answer proposes using it for "Any time there is something that represents more than its literal meaning", which I think is what we did back then)
Should we remove the meaning and symbolism tags? (in which a proposal to remove these two big tags got a net score of +3, but evidently wasn't implemented)


If we decide to do this, I volunteer to do the actual edits. I've done major tag clean-ups before on Puzzling (open-ended, cryptography) by slow, 3-at-a-time edits, to avoid flooding the front page.

@bobble heh, someone still needs to finish killing off [word-problem] on Puzzling; I was doing slow 3-at-a-time edits for that but kind of petered out :-)

Let's not start editing before we have reached agreement about what we want the tags to mean (if we change anything at all). I have not gone through all the [tag:symbolism] questions, so (1) I can't say whether the way we use the tag has changed or the nature of our questions and (2) I haven't retagged any such questions recently. (3) Not answerable without going through existing questions.

Three considerations:

The purpose of tags is not the categorization of knowledge, but to help people find questions that they might be interested in answering.

It is good if people asking questions can choose appropriate tags for their own questions.

It requires some expertise to distinguish between the various literary figures (symbol, metaphor, simile, conceit, allegory, personification, etc.) and in many cases there is overlap or a mixture. (Consider, for example, this question.)


For these reasons I recommend not trying to make fine distinctions in the tagging system, but to have broad tags that don't require much expertise to apply. We could have one tag for all kinds of figures, with tag synonyms for each individual kind of figure.
For concreteness, I propose the following plan, though I am not attached to the details:

We use a single tag for all kinds of figures. I suggest  literary-figure but other names would work.

The tag excerpt is along these lines: "Questions about literary figures, that is, devices in which one thing represents another thing. Literary figures include allegories, metaphors, and symbols."

The allegory, metaphor, symbolism tags are made into aliases for the tag created in step 1.

Add a note to the excerpt for literary-device mentioning that figures have their own tag (figures are a subset of devices).


In this suggestion, I'm using "figure" in the following sense:

figure, n. 7.a. Something which denotes or represents another thing allegorically, metaphorically, or symbolically
Oxford English Dictionary.

However, if this sense of the word is too obscure, the tag could be named figurative-device.

I like the idea of having a tag which correctly covers all these things together, but I wasn't aware of the term "literary figure" and I doubt most casual site viewers would be either (it might get misunderstood to mean "figure" as in person, for example). What about something like figurative-technique? The adjective "figurative" might be less likely to be misunderstood than the noun "figure" (although maybe "technique" isn't the best second word, anything else we could use there?)

Allegory is not just a figurative device, it is a structural technique. A metaphor is not a symbol. Not all symbols are allegorical. Symbolism, allegory, and metaphor are three entirely different things, and I don't see the point of conflating them into a single tag.

@verbose I made an argument at the start of this answer explaining why it is not a good idea to try to make difficult distinctions in the tag system. See the "Three considerations" section and the paragraph starting "For these reasons".
